# Highlighting part of the text in DataGrid Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, highlighting

I want to highlight the strings in data grid in a WPF application.
In WinForms there is a `CellPainting` event that helps us in fulfilling this purpose.
I am unable to locate anything in WPF.

I want to highlight **part of TEXT** that is present in a cell, **not whole cell**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You Can:

add a DataGridTemplateColumn. In the template place a TextBlock.
Then, **Option 1**: insert in your textBlock Run's. Set their Format. And Bind the Run's to your Data. **Option 2**: set the Content of TextBlock in procedural code, via converter ect.

## **Option 1**

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="{Binding xx}" Background="Yellow" />
                    <Run Text="{Binding yy}" />
                </TextBlock>                            
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

## **Option 2**

**XAML**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <myns:ConvertToFormatedRuns xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:YourProjectName" />
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Label>
            <Label.Content>
                <MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource ConvertToFormatedRuns}>
                    <Binding Path="xxx" />
                    <Binding Path="yyy" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

**CODE**

```
public class ConvertToFormatedRuns : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var tb = new TextBlock();

        tb.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = (string)values[0], Background = Brushes.Yellow });
        tb.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = (string)values[1]});

        return tb;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also Drawning like WinForms, but is Unnecessary and not recommended.

Comment: my requirement is bit complex. will try above procedure to solve it. we can drawing like WinForms, what does that mean ?